# JavaScript: удалить <div> блок через id

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в JavaScript(без использования jQuery и пр. библиотек) удалить полностью конструкцию блока `<div id="id1"></div>` и его содержиоме:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="id1">
        <span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Должно получиться:

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="id2">
        <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("id1").remove();
```

```html
<div id="main">
     <div id="id1">
        <span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Например так:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("main");
var child = document.getElementById("id1");
parent.removeChild(child);
```

```html
<div id="main">
     <div id="id1">
        <span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Примерно как-то так:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("id1");
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

```html
<style>
div[id^="id"] {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div id="main">
     <div id="id1">
        <span class="class1"> Текст1 </span>
    </div>
    <div id="id2">
        <span class="class2"> Текст2 </span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Я думаю, что будет весьма полезно изучить этот [познавательный ресурс](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-removechild) :)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("id1").outerHTML='';
```

[Поддержка браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=outerHTML)

Остается добавить, что способ преложенный **Elena Semenchenko** более многословный, но более железобетонный.
   Способ предложенный **Dmitriy Kondratiuk** более ясный, но в ослах например не заработает.

Comment: outerHTML - это всёж функция Замены и необходимые задачи лучше решать такими-же специальными функциями - заточенными под это.

Для удаления есть: getElementById(id).remove();

Answer (score 0):

У меня дивы удаляют сами себя по примерно такой схеме через клик:

```
function removeDiv(IdDiv){ document.getElementById(IdDiv).remove(); }

 onclick="removeDiv(this.id)";
```

Онклик конечноже можно заменить на любое другое и вызываться как угодно.